# Avoid Scriptlets in Jsp for displaying data on page load

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, scope, scriptlet

I realize that when you submit the form in a jsp, in the mapped servlet you can get the desired data, set it in the proper scope(say request) and forward it to jsp like this:

```
request.setAttribute("myList", myList); // Store list in request scope.
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

However am wondering for pages which doesn't have a form or in other words we want to display data as soon as page loads, how can we efficiently load the data without using scriptlets like

```
<%= myBean.populateData("String Argument_1")%>
```

Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide any recommendations around the same.

Comment: Just use `doGet()` instead of `doPost()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the request comes from a form or not doesn't change anything. The servlet receives a request, and then can do some processing and forward to a JSP:

1. servlet gets request parameters
2. servlets uses those parameters to get requested data from a database, and populate some beans with said data. It may also build some beans from scratch, to display a form with default values
3. servlet puts those beans in request attributes
4. servlet forwards to a JSP
5. JSP avoids using scriptlets and rather uses JSP EL, the JSTL and custom tags to display the information stored in the beans in request scope

Comment: But how will i send the request to Servlet on page load without using scriptlets?

Comment: In a properly designed MVC application, you don't have any link or form pointing to the URL of a JSP. They all point to the URL of a Servlet (or Filter), which forwards to a JSP.

Comment: Add a welcome file to your web.xml. Create a meta refresh like: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/myapp/WelcomeServlet" />`.

You have a lot of options here, but the above is easy and works.

Answer (score 0):

I think using EL in combination with JSTL can help you in the most common situations. If this is not enough you can write EL functions or your own custom tags.